# Suppressing someone's money

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary

When someone owes someone else a sum of money and they are NOT paying it back, they don't even intend to give it back to the lender, it is kind of suppressing, right? But I don't feel it is natural to say:

> He **suppressed** my money.

I don't know why it sounds a little weird to me, maybe because you suppress someone's right, as I've read  but do we suppress someone's property too, e.g. money?

Answer (score 3):

It's not "suppressing", that doesn't fit any of the dictionary definitions.

"Withhold" is possible:  "He withheld my money".  It means "refuse to give (back) something that that is due or expected." Or simply "He didn't pay his debt."